# Why can't I pass in proper input shape to layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

For the CNN discriminator that I'm building, although I specify an input shape of `(1, 19)`, I need to pass in a tensor of shape `(1,1,19)` for it to work. Why is this? I've added code below (refer to the first line when I define input shape)

```
def make_critic(input_shape=(1,19)):
    # weight initialization
    init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)
    # weight constraint
    const = ClipConstraint(0.01)
    
    Input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, kernel_initializer=init, kernel_constraint=const, input_shape=input_shape)(Input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, kernel_initializer=init, kernel_constraint=const)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    
    # linear activation
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    Output = layers.Dense(units=1)(x)
    
    # compile model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Input, outputs=Output)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.00005)
    model.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=opt)
    return model

discriminator = make_critic()
discriminator.summary()
```

```
Model: "functional_22"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        [(None, 19, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_23 (Conv1D)           (None, 19, 64)            128       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (Batc (None, 19, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_22 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 19, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_24 (Conv1D)           (None, 19, 64)            4160      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (Batc (None, 19, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_23 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 19, 64)            0
```

**So this works (passing in a tensor of shape (1,1,19)):** `discriminator(tf.reshape(tf.concat([msft_data[0], msft_data[1]], 0), (1, 1,19)))`

**But this doesn't although it's the proper input shape**
`discriminator(tf.reshape(tf.concat([msft_data[0], msft_data[1]], 0), (1, 19)))`

Comment: You seem to be forgetting about the samples dimension which is implicit in any input layer, so if you specify input_shape=(2,), the actual input should be compatible with (None, 2).

Comment: So do you mean that when you define the input shape in a model you omit batch size specifications but when you actually feed it into the layer an extra dimension needs to be added for batch_size?

Comment: Yes basically, its not batch size but samples dimension.

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Conv1D layer expects 3Dimension input `[batch_size, time_steps, feature_size]`. Input shape `(1,1,19)` is expected. Thanks!